# Сделать выбранным option при переходе на конкретную ссылку

Tags: php, html, html-select

есть такой select:

```
<select class="selection-2" name="sorting"  onchange="window.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
<option value="?sort=nosort">Без сортировки</option>
<option value="?sort=new">Новое</option>
<option value="?sort=popular">Популярное</option>
<option value="?sort=price-asc">Цена: по возрасанию</option>
<option value="?sort=price-desc">Цена: по убыванию</option>
</select>
```

Как сделать так, что-бы при переходе по выбранному **option** в ячейке **select** показывало название. Например: при переходе "?sort=popular" в ячейке select показывало  "Популярное"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ознакомительный пример "как это сделать именно на php":

```
<select class="selection-2" name="sorting" onchange="window.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
  <option value="?sort=nosort">Без сортировки</option>
  <option value="?sort=new">Новое</option>
  <option value="?sort=popular" <?php=($_GET['sort']=='popular' ? 'selected':''?> >Популярное</option>
  <option value="?sort=price-asc">Цена: по возрасанию</option>
  <option value="?sort=price-desc">Цена: по убыванию</option>
</select>
```

В тегах же был php? =)

Comment: да, но мне надо, что-бы при переходе на определенный option показывало определенный option (идет обновление страницы)

Comment: В примере показано как сделать на popular , добавьте тоже самое условие к остальным и радуйтесь.

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо!